# Missing text format: 4 - ckeditor issue

Tags: input-formats

"Missing text format: 4." reported in log from anonymous user - I have Restricted HTML enabled for anonymous user

Drupal 9.3.8[image]

This really fills the log - it seems a common issue for the anonymous user

What exactly is " text format: 4 "

Anyone know how to drill into this for a fix ??

Comment: This is when you display a formatted text. Roles don't matter, but the text format which a user has stored in the past together with the formatted text has to exist to display the text, which is for "4" not the case, obviously.

Comment: Is there a way you know to fix or reset this to make it go away ??

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue you can either recreate the text format `4`:

- *admin/config/content/formats/add*
- Name: *4*
- Machine name: `4` (automatically assigned)

Which probably existed when the text fields where saved originally, either on your site or a different site you have imported the data from.

Or re-save the formatted text fields switching to the text format *Restricted HTML* (`restricted_html`) you want to use now.

Comment: OK . . .  thanks . . . but I have no idea which is text format 4, nor which text fields are involved.  I will digaround and try a few things.